# Can I use tartaric acid in cider(apple wine) to decrease ph

Tags: cider, acidity

From the things I've read apples don't contain tartaric acid and some websites say to use malic acid and I've found 1 that says to use tartaric and not malic. Tartaric is more readily available to me, is there any good reasons I shouldn't use Tartaric acid?

Comment: Not quite an answer: it's a common food additive (E334), so why not?

Comment: Also, higher pH (numerically) means more basic, not acidic. You should say 'lower pH'

Comment: oops changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tartic acid has a more tart/sour flavor. Malic is a little bit smoother. You can use less malic 2.7g a gallon compared to 3.8g a gallon to lower the ph 0.1.